# Regression selection using all possible subsets selection and automatic selection techniques

Tags: r, regression, model-selection, stepwise-regression

Given the dataset [cars.txt](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/138632/statistics/R%20data/cars.txt), we want to formulate a good regression model for the Midrange Price using the variables Horsepower, Length, Luggage, Uturn, Wheelbase, and Width. Both:

1. using all possible subsets selection, and
2. using an automatic selection technique.

For the first part, we do in R:

```
cars <- read.table(file=file.choose(), header=TRUE)
names(cars)

#regression
attach(cars)
leap <- leaps(x=cbind(cars$Horsepower, cars$Length, cars$Luggage, cars$Uturn, cars$Wheelbase, cars$Width), 
y=cars$MidrangePrice, method=c("r2"), nbest=3)
combine <- cbind(leap$which,leap$size, leap$r2)
n <- length(leap$size)
dimnames(combine) <- list(1:n,c("horsep","length","Luggage","Uturn","Wheelbase","Width","size","r2"))
round(combine, digits=3)

leap.cp <- leaps(x=cbind(cars$Horsepower, cars$Length, cars$Luggage, cars$Uturn, cars$Wheelbase, cars$Width), 
y=cars$MidrangePrice, nbest=3)
combine.cp <- cbind(leap.cp$which,leap.cp$size, leap.cp$Cp)
dimnames(combine.cp) <- list(1:n,c("horsep","length","Luggage","Uturn","Wheelbase","Width","size","cp"))
round(combine.cp, digits=3)
plot(leap.cp$size, leap.cp$Cp, ylim=c(1,7))
abline(a=0, b=1)
```

Am I correct in my interpretation that the most adequate model is one with 4 parameters (the three variables Horsepower, Wheelbase and Width) because it has the lowest Mallows' Cp value?

For the second part, we can choose between the forward, backward or stepwise selection models:

```
#stepwise selection methods
#forward
slm.foward <- step(lm(cars$MidrangePrice ~1, data=cars), scope=~cars$Horsepower + cars$Length + cars$Luggage + cars$Uturn + cars$Wheelbase + cars$Horsepower+ cars$Width, direction="forward")

#backward
reg.lm1 <- lm(cars$MidrangePrice ~ cars$Horsepower + cars$Length + cars$Luggage + cars$Uturn + cars$Wheelbase + cars$Horsepower + cars$Width)
slm.backward <- step(reg.lm1, direction="backward")


#stepwise
reg.lm1 <- lm(cars$MidrangePrice ~ cars$Horsepower + cars$Length + cars$Luggage + cars$Uturn + cars$Wheelbase + cars$Horsepower + cars$Width)
slm.stepwise <- step(reg.lm1,direction="both")
```

How do I interpret the results I get from this R code?

Comment: you have 6 independent variables, is there a particular reason you need only a subset of them in your model? Why not including all of them?

Comment: isn't this a homework assignment?

Comment: @mpiktas It is not a homework assignment, but the R code does indeed come from a course I'm following. The course text is very short on how to interpret the derived results and I posted here trying to get a better grasp on the material while stuyding.

Comment: I'd suggest to give the "bestglm" package a try. I uses leaps internally but gives you the possibility to use AIC, BIC, ... or even cross-validation as a basis for model selection.

Comment: I agree w/ mpiktas, there is no reason to need a subset of your variables, & further w/ Frank Harrell below that stepwise selection methods are certain to lead you astray. If that doesn't make sense / you want to understand why, you may want to read my answer here: [algorithms-for-automatic-model-selection](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20836//20856#20856).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the second part, you must interpret the output as the steps towards your final model.

For example, in the forward case you begin with
    Start:  AIC=377.95
    cars$MidrangePrice ~ 1

```
              Df Sum of Sq    RSS    AIC
+ cars$Horsepower  1    4979.3 3054.9 300.66
+ cars$Wheelbase   1    3172.3 4862.0 338.76
+ cars$Length      1    2448.8 5585.4 350.14
+ cars$Width       1    1969.2 6065.0 356.89
+ cars$Uturn       1    1450.2 6584.0 363.63
+ cars$Luggage     1    1079.6 6954.7 368.12
<none>                         8034.2 377.95
```

Your current model is only considering the constant `cars$MidrangePrice ~ 1`.

Each row in the table indicates that in case you add that variable (for example, Horsepower), you will get the following results rearding `Sq` `RSS`(Residual Sum of Squares) and `AIC` (Akaike Information Criterion).

In the other cases you must read the results the same way.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 7):

Stepwise regression in the absence of penalization is frought with so many difficulties that I'm surprised people are still using it.  The web has long lists of problems, starting with the extremely low probability of finding the "right" model.